# Find rows with parameter in one of two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table and need help

```
Friends:

My_E_Mail (VARCHAR) Friends_E_Mail(VARCHAR) 
alester@pam.com carl@pam.com
alester@pam.com greg@pam.com
alester@pam.com jude@pam.com
```

What I need to do is select either `My_E_Mail` or `Friend_E_Mail` that does not match a parameter that I plug in using? 
For example:

```
select Friend_E_Mail
From Friends 
WHERE Friend_E_Mail NOT IN(?)
```

My question is how to select one or the other column depending on that parameter if you plug in.

Let's say I plug in carl@pam.com the only thing that should come up is Alester because Carl is friends with just alester not Greg and Jude.

Every time I make a statement myself I get it to show all of Alesters friends
but when I plug in Carl I also see Jude and Greg even thought they are not friends.
Also I "CAN NOT" create anther table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can see that you have a SQL problem from the tags alone.  The title should give some context. Perhaps you could edit your title to be more meaningful.

Comment: what should ii change it to?

Comment: Something like "Find rows with parameter in one of two columns?" ?

Comment: how are the 'my' or 'friend' being selected? Or do you want the sql to select it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code will help you

```
select Friend_E_Mail
From Friends 
WHERE 'carl@pam.com' NOT IN(Friend_E_Mail, My_E_Mail)
```

Comment: @JamesPutin I've read it again. If you want to select `Friends_E_Mail` you will never see `alester@pam.com` because alester is in `My_E_Mail` column. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELCARE @email VARCHAR(50) = ?
WITH FRIENDS_CTE (My_E_Mail, Friend_E_Mail)
AS
(
  SELECT My_E_Mail, Friends_E_Mail
  FROM FRIENDS
  WHERE My_E_Mail = @email
  UNION 
  SELECT Friends_E_Mail, My_E_Mail
  FROM FRIENDS
  WHERE Friends_E_Mail = @email
)
SELECT Friend_E_Mail
FROM FRIENDS_CTE
WHERE My_E_Mail = @email
```