# SQL Selecting One Entire column based on from parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this table and need help:

**`Friends`**:

- `My_E_Mail` (`VARCHAR`) AND
- `Friends_E_Mail` (`VARCHAR`)

These are some sample values:

```
alester@pam.com carl@pam.com
alester@pam.com greg@pam.com
alester@pam.com jude@pam.com
```

What I need to do is select either `My_E_Mail` or `Friend_E_Mail` that does not match a parameter that I plug in using `?` in SQL Server 2008 using.

For example:

```
select Friend_E_Mail
From Friends 
WHERE Friend_E_Mail NOT IN (?)
```

What I want to do is show a list of friends for each person. For example alester has 3 friends but each of those others people only have one friend which is alester.

Also I cannot create another table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show some more sample data from that table `Friends` with another example? It is not clear what are you trying to do through the example you gave.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something isn't this what you are looking for? `SELECT My_E_Mail FROM Friends WHERE Friend_E_mail = ?`

Comment: what i want to do is show a list of friend for each person alester has 3 friends but each of those others people only have one friend which is alester.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to find all friends of "*X*" regardless whether "*X*" belongs to `My_E_mail` or `Friends_E_Mail`?

Comment: [How is this question different from what you just asked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524961/find-rows-with-parameter-in-one-of-two-columns)

Comment: its not different no one answered the first question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a UNION Is what you need:

```
declare @email varchar(50)
set @email = ?

SELECT
    Friend_E_Mail as email
FROM    
    Friends 
WHERE 
    My_E_Mail = @email
    and Friend_E_Mail <> @email
UNION
SELECT 
    My_E_Mail as email
FROM 
    Friends 
WHERE 
    Friend_E_Mail = @email
    and My_E_Mail <> @email
```

This code will return three rows for alester@pam.com but only one row for each of the other three.

Note that UNION will only return DISTINCT rows.  If you need to keep duplicates, use UNION ALL.  In addition, if you know ahead of time that the results will be distinct, use UNION ALL, to save the performance cost that comes with DISTINCT.

Comment: i would upvote but im new thank you again! THIS IS THE ANSWER !!! **W00t**

Answer (score 0):

The below query return the entire row (not just 1 field).  If the basic logic match you need it can be modified to produce just a single column with `CASE - WHEN` structures.

```
select *
From Friends 
WHERE My_E_Mail = ? OR Friend_E_Mail = ?
```